# jQuery replace a given link with another

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a lot of links I have to modify. I have to replace each url of them with a hardcoded link.

For example `path/to/something.html?L` into `this/is/the/right/path.html?L`

Everything until **`?L`** has to be replaced. Everything in first path until the `?L` parameter is dynamic.

How could I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it this way,

```
prev = $('a[href^=path/to/something.html]').attr('href')
required = prev.split('?')[1];

$('a[href^=path/to/something.html]').attr('href', 'this/is/the/right/path.html?' + required);
```

Comment: You need to add the "?" to the new attribute or else it will just add the "required" to the href.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$('a[href="path/to/something.html?L"]').attr('href', 'this/is/the/right/path.html?L')
```

Basically what it says is to find all the links with a certain href and replace the href with the new one.

Is L a constant or is it just for an example and L can be multiple things?

Comment: path/to/something.html can be any other link instead of the ?L parameter

Comment: Ok then Adil's answer will serve better.

Comment: But after die ?L can be more different parameters but i think this is a good breakpoint

Comment: then you need to split the href where the "?" is and replace only the first part with the new link. Adil's answer shows you how!